Do Israeli quadcopters play sounds to lure people out of their homes?
According to this report by Middle East Eye, "War on Gaza: Israeli drones lure Palestinians with crying children recordings then shoot them
", drones are playing sounds of babies crying and women and children in distress to "lure" residents out, they further claim,

According to the residents, the audio recordings also included

songs in both Hebrew and Arabic,
including children’s songs,
sounds of clashes and moving tanks,
voices of Palestinian armed men, and
voices of local roaming vendors of cleaning products familiar to residents of Gaza.


They only provide one clip that I see of video evidence, which they claim is from the Nuseirat refugee camp. They also have interviews from residents in Gaza.
Is this true? Is there any external evidence of this claim not present in the report by Middle East Eye, or any other reputable news outlets picking this up?

TBH this rather improbable "A significant event involving the use of quadcopters occurred during the "flour massacre" on 11 January, on al-Rasheed street near the Gaza City coastline. Numerous witnesses recounted quadcopters firing upon hundreds of individuals awaiting the arrival of aid trucks." Israel has far more capable drones and quadcopters generally are too small to carry firearms (although there were some rare modifications in Ukraine). The far more typical weapon for quadcopters are dropped grenades. So, the whole story seems pretty shoddy to me.

OTOH, quadcopters with speakers were sometimes used in Ukraine for propaganda/annoyance purposes. BTW, the MEE photo shows a hexacopter labelled as a quad. The former can lift more stuff and drop mortar rounds. (Sometimes called 'Baba Yaga' in Ukraine, in this role.)

Every other question you asked about a claim by Middle Eye Beast was a clear fake. In this case there is nothing to falsify as their only proof is a blacked out video with a crying baby soundtrack. There is nothing there than can indicate that it's a drone, that the voices are coming from the drone or that the video originates from Gaza. In any case, Israel has used previously, with videoed evidence, drones with loudspeakers to warn bystanders to leave a conflict area or to avoid engaging. This claim would be a complete reversal of known and documented previous behavior.

In addition, this seems as a case of projection as there are documented evidences of Hamas using a similar tactic (fake children, children's equipment and loudspeakers with children's' voices) to try and draw IDF forces into ambushes. Here is a (Hebrew speaking) example from Dec. 2023 https://www.tiktok.com/@arutz_7/video/7312800770871561479

@SIMEL What would you expect a video of the night sky to look like?

@thegodsfromengineering There are sources of Israel buying octocopters with machine guns, and quadcopters (video in operation by Haaretz.com)

@EvanCarroll: possibly. Except for a single story in 2017 I've not found out much on that. They might be keeping it a secret. Or they bought a few, tested them, didn't work well and it was quietly shelved.

We know they have them in two form factors (at least). So "quadcopters generally are too small to carry firearms" isn't true. There is apparently at least one company that sells them for military use.

@EvanCarroll, if the claim is that Israel is doing it at night with the quadcopters you liked to, then it can't happen at night, as it's clearly seen that those drones don't have nigh vision capabilities. And the only footage we have of those drones is from their testing years ago or their manufacturers website. We have no evidence that they were used in Gaza or anywhere else by Israel or anyone else. The photo in the article is of a drone Israel uses to fire non-lethal tear gas at protesters.

@EvanCarroll, as to what I expect is to see extraordinary evidence to an extraordinary claim. Especially when it comes from a source know to spread false news.

@SIMEL re "those drones don't have nigh vision capabilities" I have a hard to believing the drone they've taken a picture of flying in the daytime, is the exact drone they claim was shooting at them at night. I don't know how they could know that. And I certainly didn't read that from the article. However, regardless, how do you know whether not that drone in the picture or otherwise had night vision? Are you an expert in drones now? What's your source?

@EvanCarroll, as for your claim. you claimed that IDF uses TIKAD drones. But when looking at their optics it's clear that they have no night vision sights. And the manufacturer's site doesn't mention anything about night capabilities in their advertising material. https://dukeroboticsys.com/ .If they want to prove such a claim they need better evidence that a black screen with some noises coming from an unknown source. I could claim that this is a Hamas drone trying to lure Israeli civilians outside with the sounds of a baby crying and there is nothing in the video contradicting it.

@SIMEL TIKAD's don't provide optics. You give them the gun, with whatever optics you want. https://youtu.be/Mmt_kTUvx8o?t=41 look at 41 seconds

@EvanCarroll, they don't say or show it in the video. They show 3 different weapons that are available. They never say that you can put any weapon you want with any sights you want. You also didn't show that this or any other drone with similar capabilities was ever used (not just tested) by the IDF.

more effort plz "tikad drone israel use in war"  https://www.discovermagazine.com/technology/israeli-military-veterans-built-a-sniper-drone "In 2015, Israeli Special Forces likely made history by using a sniper rifle mounted on a commercial drone to take out a target. The robotic solution that achieved such pinpoint accuracy came from Duke Robotics, a startup founded by veterans of the Israel Defense Forces. That startup has since developed a multi-rotor sniper drone capable of accurately firing a wide array of weapons such as military assault rifles and grenade launchers."

Duke Robotics was bought by an Israeli company in 2021 (or 2020) https://www.israeldefense.co.il/en/node/48248 Not too clear how much their sniper drones are employed/bought though. But at least their testing grounds were moved to Israel too https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2022/06/01/2454291/0/en/UAS-Drone-s-Subsidiary-Duke-Robotics-to-Move-its-Operations-to-a-Science-Industry-Park-with-Adjacent-Drone-Testing-Zone.html

@SIMEL: Lack of IR camera in ads is not much of a show stopper. Ukraine easily adapted their agricultural Baba Yagas with that. And even showing up on the cheaper FPV drones lately, over there.

OTOH IR cameras generally have lower resolution for the same size, so I'm somewhat skeptical one can easily make the replacement on a sniper drone. But one can operate closer at night without risking counter-fire so YMMV. Still the hexa and octo-copters are pretty loud, so getting closer means they could be heard, negating some advantage of night ops.

Yes, I did have a BDS Movement gravatar previously, what about it? I'll return to it again shortly (likely in another two weeks).

FWTW, the IDF releases some footage of them operating large quads in Gaza, but like in Ukraine, they're dropping bombs/mines https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/1d6njeb/idf_using_large_drones_to_drop_munitions_on_hamas/

Here are some different sources:

AJ+ post on Twitter - 18 Apr 2024:
These are testimonies of Palestinians who thought they heard children and women screaming for help in Gaza's Nuseirat refugee camp, only to realize that the cries were coming from an Israeli drone broadcasting distress calls to lure them out so it could shoot them.

EuroMedMonitor - 16 Apr 2024: Israeli army broadcasts intimidating sounds to lure, kill, and forcibly displace civilians in the Nuseirat camp

Al Jazeera Journalist post on Instagram - 16 Apr 2024: documented yesterday in the Nuseirat refugee camp is extremely shocking.
Israeli drones mimicked the sounds of crying children, women’s screams, and barking dogs to lure residents out of their homes, only to target and kill them.

Middle East Eye
post on Twitter - 16 Apr 2024
: Israeli drones are reported emitting sounds of crying children at al-Nuseirat camp in Gaza to target and shoot civilians searching for the source of the distress calls.



I am concerned that these still sound like propaganda combined with urban myths. The first video's translation says the sounds are "just like what you are hearing" - it isn't primary evidence. The third and fourth video is the same as the first, and add nothing. The second report is entirely unclear on whether they were first-hand accounts or rumours: "Testimonies from camp residents, which were provided to the Euro-Med Monitor team". All were anonymous. I don't have an opinion on the truthfulness, but I did not find this answer convincing, as it looks exactly like an urban legend.

@Oddthinking Do you expect the people who are under the most brutal bombardment and hunger and thirst for 7 months to prepare a full HD video for you? I am surprised that you accept Israeli propaganda without documents unless they are refuted, but you are suspicious of the news of people in famine and under bombardment until a strong and extraordinary document is presented. What kind of document can convince people to see if such a document can be provided or not? Just remember the propaganda of the 40 beheaded children that many still believe.

I will not respond to such nonsense. Try again.

@Oddthinking The OP asks "Is there any external evidence of this claim".

Downvoted because two of the links are the same video as the OP.  You can't provide "external evidence" by citing someone else posting the same video.

@Bobson feel free to edit the answer.
